# Firebird and VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, firebird

I have a problem with `Firebird` for VisualStudio 2013. I install `FirebirdDDEX 3.0.2`, `FirebirdClient 4.5.1.0`. It's registered in gacutil and edit machine.config.

It's work fine, but yesterday i got this error:

### Error message:

> When you attempt to update a database exception occurred type
>   "System.ArgumentException". Exception message: "Unable to convert the connection string for the runtime to the equivalent line for the development
>       time. Connection string: character set = NONE;
>       initial catalog = g:\work\ Mash\new_form\base\FORM2016-1.GDB;
>       userid = **; password = **; datasource = 192.168.1.1"

`machine.config` v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319:

```
     ................
     <configSections>
       <section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=%RunTimeVersion%, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
     </configSections>
     ................
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider"invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>            
     </DbProviderFactories>
     ................
     %RunTimeVersion% - 2.0.0.0 or 4.0.0.0
```

GacUtils info:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

In dataproviders Firebird don't show again.

I try solve this problem 2 days without result. I try reinstall firebird ddex, firebird client and delete all firebird in machine.config. Can anybody help me with this issue?

UPD: install last version FirebirdClient 5.0.5 and have the same error.

Comment: update the firebird provider to 5.0.5 and try again.

Comment: Have the same error...

Comment: where do you get this message?

Comment: In Model ADO.NET EDM, when i try to refresh a model of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem in Firebird server. On the server the request is stuck, so Firebird server don't resolve. Then I connected a new `.edmx` model and it is working.